# Importing D3 using NPM?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am having trouble getting d3 to import properly after an npm install. The import seems successful with either a d3 download or a script tag as [per the documentation](https://d3js.org/), but both of these seem like a slight antipattern to me, as I'm used to importing my dependencies with a tool like npm or yarn.

After running npm install d3 and when trying to import the library, I see the following errors in the browser console after opening my index.html

[image]

js1.js

```
import d3 from 'd3';

const greetings = function js1(greeting)
{
    console.log("Hello from js1" + greeting);
    const selectedelement = d3.select(some_element)
    ...

}
```

index.html

```
<head>
    <script src="js1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<div>
    <script language="javascript">
        greetings("HALLO");
    </script>
...
```

package.json

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "d3": "^6.2.0"
  }
```

package-lock.json

```
...
  "dependencies": {
...
    "d3": {
      "version": "6.2.0",
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
```

See more in [the document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3)